Question about Gaussian Spherical Mapping, do carmo
I have a question about the following section in Do Carmo. Here, the author provides a geometric interpretation of the self-adjoint operator $S_{\eta}(x)$ defined in the following manner:

where

and $X, Y$ are vector fields defined on an submanifold $M$ embedded into a larger manifold $\overline{M}$, and $\overline{X}, \overline{Y}$ local extensions of $X, Y$ to $\overline{M}$.
In particular, he introduces the Gaussian mapping:

Question:

In the second to last sentence, Do carmo states that "$\langle N, N \rangle = 1$ guarantees that $\overline{\nabla}_x N$" has vanishing normal component. How does he arrive at this?

What I tried: Taking the covariant derivative of $\langle N, N \rangle = 1$, it follows that
$$
\langle \overline{\nabla}_x N, N \rangle = 0
$$
Thus, $\overline{\nabla}_x N$ is orthogonal to $N$, but this by itself is not enough to imply $\overline{\nabla}_x N$ lies within the tangent space of $N$ (or is it)?

The tangent space $T_NS^n$ of the unit sphere $S^n \subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$ at a unit vector $N \in S^n$ is precisely the linear subspace $N^{\perp} \subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$.

You might develop more intuition and learn some concrete examples by reading through a curves and surfaces book before launching into the graduate material that generalizes it. My own text is freely available by clicking on my profile page.
